# Select method of fullcalendar works more than once

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to make a calendar instance using full calander. In the select method, I've already made it display a modal when the alert () function is running. But the whole problem began here.

```js
select: function(arg) {
  $("#modal-success").modal('show');
  $('#eventSubmit').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(arg);
    calendar.addEvent({
      title: $('#eventTitle').val(),
      start: arg.startStr + "T" + $('#eventTime').val(),
      color: "green"

    });
    calendar.unselect();
    $("#modal-success").modal('hide');
  });
},
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/bootstrap/main.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.2.0/bootstrap/main.css" />

<div class="modal modal-success fade" id="modal-success">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Etkinlik başlığını ve saatini giriniz</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Etkinlik Adı</label>
            <input type="text" id="eventTitle" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Etkinlik Saati</label>
            <div class="input-group" data-date-format="HH:mm">

              <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="eventTime" name="eventTime" class="form-control timepicker" required>

              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
        <input type="button" id="eventSubmit" class="btn btn-outline" value="Kaydet">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Console.log(arg) output (1 submit):

```
{start: Wed Oct 16 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00), end: Thu Oct 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00), startStr: "2019-10-16", endStr: "2019-10-17", allDay: true, …}
```

Console.log(arg) output (2 submit):

```
{start: Wed Oct 16 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00), end: Thu Oct 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00), startStr: "2019-10-16", endStr: "2019-10-17", allDay: true, …}

{start: Thu Oct 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00), end: Fri Oct 18 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00), startStr: "2019-10-17", endStr: "2019-10-18", allDay: true, …}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, can you please share full code of initialization of FullCalendar. And how exactly do you think that select is executing more than once ?

Comment: I made you a snippet and removed the illegal `<p></p>`  - please update the script part with relevant script

Comment: the problem is because you put $('#eventSubmit').on inside the "select". This just keeps adding more and more event handlers to your button each time you select a time. And you never remove the previous ones. So whenever you click submit, all the event handlers attached to the element will fire, including the ones relating to earlier selections. This is a common mistake and anti-pattern in JS/event-based programming. Either remove the previous event handlers first, or move this handler to somewhere it will only be called once, and find a way to pass the relevant data into it.